# Pandas - interpolate with reference

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, interpolation

Folks, i am trying to interpolate with reference. I have the below dataframe:

```
       0     1    2    size
0   JJEL  16.0   22.7  NaN
16  JJEL  18.0   NaN   1.0
17  JJEL  21.0   NaN   1.0
1   JJEL  37.5  29.9   NaN
```

I want to interpolate the NaN at column'2' by the growying of the column '1'. The growth is linear, it is like 16.0 to 37.5 was at 'X' and 22.7 to 29.9 was at 'Y'. if i just interpolate using

```
df = df[2].fillna(df[2].interpolate())
```

it consider the 'X' at a cartesian plan like 1, 2, 3. I need make it consider 16.0 ate the initial and 37.5 at finaly.

Comment: Just did. Think now it is more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting column 1 as the index and interpolating with `method='index'`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'JJEL', 16: 'JJEL', 17: 'JJEL', 1: 'JJEL'},
                   1: {0: 16.0, 16: 18.0, 17: 21.0, 1: 37.5},
                   2: {0: 22.7, 16: np.nan, 17: np.nan, 1: 29.9},
                   'size': {0: np.nan, 16: 1.0, 17: 1.0, 1: np.nan}})

df[2] = df.set_index(1)[2].interpolate(method='index').to_numpy()

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
       0     1          2  size
0   JJEL  16.0  22.700000   NaN
16  JJEL  18.0  23.369767   1.0
17  JJEL  21.0  24.374419   1.0
1   JJEL  37.5  29.900000   NaN
```